# How to handle the extra elements added to solve incosistent dimensions of arrays in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Maybe the question is too basic, but I have some problem to understand how to prepare my data so that I can plot a boxplot.
So, I have a

```
data = 1x30000 struct % with a column name temperature and year
```

In each row *(i)* the temparatures are for example values saved in the following format [5.33; 3.222; 1.456]. And each row has **different number of elements**. Some are *123x1 double* and others for example *50x1 double*.

To extract all of the data I have created a variable timestamps where I saved all of the index-es of the rows which values I would like to get. And I have a further variable with number_of_years And I make the following call:

```
for i=1:length(number_of_years)  
     extracted_values = [extracted_values data(timestamps).temperatures]   
end
```

So my idea is in each iteration the *extracted_values* should keep the old ones and add the new values.
But, I get an

> Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

I am sure this problem was already asked, and I believe a solution is to check the number of elements of each array and add zeros or ones so that they have the same size. But, I still dont understand how could I use that array, which will have extra zeros/ones, later to plot my barchart? How could I control the values!?

Comment: You want to plot a boxplot for the temperatures for each year? Why not ask how to do that instead of complicating things with half a solution and asking about how to fix your solution? This question looks like a classical example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/376604).

Comment: Do you know what it means to solve a system where the number of equations is different from the number of variables? You would need to figure that out first outside of SO. Otherwise, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239414/how-to-find-argmin-best-fit-optimize-for-an-overdetermined-quadratic-system-for) on the same day happens to ask about optimizing for overdetermined system.