# How to find argmin/best fit/optimize for an overdetermined quadratic system for multiple variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 100 equations with 5 variables. Is there a function in Matlab which I can use to find the optimal solution of these equations?

My problem is to find argmin ||(a-ic)^2 + (b-jd)^2 + e - h(i,j)|| over all i, j from -10 to 10. ie.

```
%% Note: not Matlab code. Just showing the Math.
for i = -10:10
    for j = -10:10
        (a-ic)^2 + (b-jd)^2 + e = h(i,j)
```

known:  `h(i,j)` is a `10*10` matrix,and `i,j` are indexes

expected: the optimal result of `a,b,c,d,e`

Comment: Is there an optimal solution? I think it is overdetermined. Maybe you just approach this problem with the statistical method and then... might be possible by using your last expressions have minimized the root mean square or some other measuring factor.

Comment: If you define a variable y  = ||(a - i c)^2 + (b - j d)^2 + e - h(i , j)||, then it is just a point with 5 variables (can say 5 dimensional) and it just look like a non-linear regression analysis. You'd better ask in more details on the [mathematics meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: can function fmincon help?

Comment: The function is only for an equation, not 100.

Comment: Use `lsqnonlin()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [`lsqnonlin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) as follows.

```
%% define a helper function in your .m file
function f = fun(x)
   a=x(1); b=x(2); c=x(3); d=x(4); e=x(5); % Using variable names from your question. In other situations, be careful when overwriting e.
   f=zeros(21*21,0);  % size(f) is taken from your question. You should make this a variable for good practice.
   for i = -10:10
      for j = -10:10
         f(10*(i+10+1)+(j+10+1)) = (a-i*c)^2 + (b-j*d)^2 + e - h(i,j); % 10 is taken from your question. 
      end
   end
end
```

(Aside, **why is your h(i,j) taking negative indices??**)

In your main function you can simply write

```
function out=myproblem(x0)
    out=lsqnonlin(@fun,x0);
end
```

In your cmd, you can call with specific initial try such as

```
myproblem([0,0,0,0,0])
```

Helper function over anonymous because in my experience helpers get sped up by JIT while anonymous do not. I also opted to reshape in the loops as an opposed to actually call `reshape` after because I expect `reshape` to cost significant extra time. Remember that O(1) in `fun` is not O(1) in `lsqnonlin`.

(As always, a solution to a nonlinear problem is not guaranteed.)